# A request to make [echo-bazaar] a synonym of [fallen-london]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The game Echo Bazaar officaly changed it's name to Fallen London back in March 2012.

Since we have a few existing questions on both the [echo-bazaar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/echo-bazaar) and [fallen-london](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallen-london) tags, and [it's purportedly the same game](http://www.failbettergames.com/?p=1093), I suggest we make [echo-bazaar](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/echo-bazaar) a synonym of [fallen-london](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallen-london).

Comment: I've just proposed some tag wiki edits which make it more obvious in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
updating post history, 8 rows affected
updating posts, 6 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 6 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [fallen-london] and [echo-bazaar] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
7 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym echo-bazaar -> fallen-london was approved!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```

Comment: You have my thanks, delicious mod.